# Pseudo-elements :before and :after vertical position

Tags: css, layout, absolute, pseudo-element

I'm trying to vertically position `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements in a `<h2>`.

Each  is placed in a `float:left` orange column, next to a another `float:left` column which contains a `<p>`.

I'd like to have at the top and the bottom of the `<h2>`, a thin border.

The issue is : if the text contained in the `<p>` float column is longer than the `<h2>`, the bottom-border of the `<h2>` is placed at the bottom of the text column, not at the bottom at the `<h2>` column.

Because of my "not-so-good-english", I made a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vcH4T/

I'm really stuck with this :(

Thanks in advance for your help!
Camille

Comment: Do you have an image of what it is you are trying to do? At the very least you have to add `position:relative` to the `h2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to have at the top and the bottom of the `<h2>`, a thin border.

Like this:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vcH4T/3/)

**CSS** /* generic h2 */

```
h2 {
    font-size:1.1em;
    line-height: 20px;
    background-color: #d8713c;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    position:relative;
}

h2::before, h2::after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    width: 10%; /* anything you like */
    margin-left:-5%; /* 50% of width */
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #efbe94;
}

h2::before {
      top: 7%;  
}

h2::after {
    bottom: 7%;

}
```

Comment: Yes! It's definitely what I want :) And, you are right : the `position:relative` of the `<h2>` was missing ... hum... Thanks a lot!!!